# Deleting Selected rows from mat-selection-list in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a simple table in angular 2 using angular material ..Implemented two methods , first is **transferSelectedRows** which on selecting rows from table pushes the row data to Selected Rows section.

Second method is **removeSelectedRows** where on selecting the rows and clicking **Remove Selected Rows** button should delete the corresponding list items.But I am unable to implement the delete functionaltiy to splice the items from the **mat-selection-list**...

Can anybody please help me out ...!

please access my sample example here ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-au6ho8?file=app%2Faccount.component.scss

### Below shown is the output of my sample angular 2 app.

[image]

### And I am getting the following error in my terminal and console.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

You can do it even with a simple array since angular5. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-klghbh?file=app%2Faccount.component.ts) for a live example.

First bind your `mat-selection-list` to the array `selectedRowsChecked` in the html file.

```
<mat-selection-list #rows [(ngModel)]="selectedRowsChecked">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let i of selectedRows" [value]="i">
        {{i.position}}-{{i.name}}-{{i.weight}}-{{i.symbol}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Then in your component define that array

```
selectedRowsChecked = [];
```

And then use this in your `removeSelectedRows` method.

```
removeSelectedRows() {
    this.selectedRowsChecked.forEach(item => {
      let index: number = this.selectedRows.findIndex(d => d === item);
      if(index > -1) {
         this.selectedRows.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    this.selectedRowsChecked = [];
}
```

Comment: yes i know .... I am able to display all the transferred rows in my console ..but unable to fetch the item selected...

Comment: If i fetch the selected item ... then its easy to splice that item

Comment: You'll need a 2nd `SelectionModel` for the transfered rows so you can see which rows are selected on the right site.

Comment: i want to implement one more functionality where on selecting rows from table and clicking on transfer button .. i need to display the the same table with only the selected rows next to previous table

Comment: Updated the stackblitz

Comment: The same as above.

Comment: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjqsj-klghbh?file=app%2Faccount.component.ts) - should be the same tho... maybe your browser has something still in cache.